# How to retrieve multiple values from the select field using Commons File Upload?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

**Update:** The problem ended up being the Flash component itself. It wasn't properly compiling the multiple values from the  element. I notified the developers and they implemented a workaround. Commons FileUpload does support multiple values per the accepted answer.

I have a form, *enctype="multipart/form-data"*, with one

```
<select name="XX" multiple="multiple">
```

and a Flash upload component which allows the user to select multiple files. When handling the POST using Apache Commons FileUpload, I detect the *select* field via

```
item.isFormField() == true
```

and continue to extract the details via

```
// Process a regular form field
if (item.isFormField()) {
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    String value = item.getString();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that **item.getString();** returns only the first selected value from the *select* field; no matter how many items I pick, I only get the first item.

Likewise, when I use the standard servlet method for parameter extraction, ie.

```
final String[] values = request.getParameterValues("XX");
```

values is empty, which I assume is because the form is encoded multipart.

How can I retrieve these multiple selected values from my multi-select field?

This (unanswered) question has also been [posed on the Sun forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5395587) by another author.

Comment: Which flash upload component you are using..? basically i do have the same requirement but not able to get the correct flash upload component.

Comment: http://www.element-it.com/multipowupload.aspx

I'm really happy with it and the developer had very quick turnaround from the time I first reported the bug to putting out a fixed version for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, several items can have the same fieldName, you just have to add all the item string values for the same fieldName to a collection of String and then convert that collection to an array.

Found some information there : 
http://www.nabble.com/RES:-File-Upload-td25910926.html

Comment: HTTP ERROR: 404

Answer (score 4):

Above link is not working and if someone else is facing same issue, here's how to fetch all values -

retrieve multiple values from the select field using Commons File Upload -

```
   List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
   Iterator iter = items.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

        if (item.isFormField()) {
           String name = item.getFieldName();
           String value = item.getString();

        if (name.equals("multi-select"))
            completeSet = value;
     }
```

then completeSet will have just first value. all other values of multi select are also in item with the same name (here **multi-select**).
So all you have to do is fetch all values one by one and then convert it into required data-type (i.e. - as collect everything in a List and convert it into String[] :) ) Eg-

```
List<String> completeSet=new ArrayList<String>();
if(name.equals("multi-select"))
     completeSet.add(value);
```

This way at the end completeSet will be having all set of values.

Comment: "String value = item.getString()" just prints as "[object File],[object File]". How do I get the 2 files as FileItems, if that just produces a string?

Comment: Nevermind - turns out the issue was the way I was passing the files in the request / issue was in the front end. Needed to add each file one at a time to the formdata, using a for loop.